# Fortran: Short form for "do loop"

Tags: loops, fortran, openmp

Hey there,
I have a code like that:

```
write (filehandle,'(5e14.6)')
     &    (((my_array(i,j,k,1),i=istart,iend,istep),j=jstart,jend,jstep),k=kstart,kend,kstep)
```

is this a short form for a "do-loop"? I couldn't find anything about it on google...
Furthermore, I'm getting an error:

> forrtl: severe (71): integer divide by
>   zero Image              PC
>   Routine            Line        Source 
>   libpthread.so.0    00007F473F0D892B 
>   Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
>   libguide.so        00007F473F3CC20E 
>   Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

when executing the program (program is parallelized with OpenMP) about THIS line (removing the line removes the error-msg). What could be the cause about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already answered, that is an implicit do-loop.

Could istep, jstep or kstep by zero?   That might lead to integer divide by zero, as the program tried to compute the number of loop iterations.

Does the program run correctly when you compile without OpenMP?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That gave my the clue: istep, jstep or kstep were zero since I forget to set them as shared in OpenMP (and yes, that's why it compiled fine without OpenMP, because all those variables were visible, but in usage with OpenMP they weren't because of default(private))! Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

Those are referred to as implicit or implied do-loops.

I don't see any division by zero in that statement, could it be one of the surrounding lines?

Comment: The strange thing is when I have something like:

write(*,*) 'test1'
write (filehandle,'(5e14.6)')
     &    (((my_array(i,j,k,1),i=istart,iend,istep),j=jstart,jend,jstep),k=kstart,kend,kstep)
write(*,*) 'test2'

I only see "test1" on my screen. When i comment out the writing-loop, I also see "test2" Oo

Comment: What does the file look like?  Does it ever get written?